# How to check the heroku database version from ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I want to check the version of my production database from a shell method running on my local MacOS development machine.  From the command line, I can successfully run

```
heroku run rake db:version --remote production
```

but if I open a `rails console` session and type in

```
hv = `heroku run rake db:version --remote production`
```

I see the following error message:

```
/Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@golf_mentor_5.0.7/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:489:in `validate_ruby!': Your Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.5.1 (Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch)
    from /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@golf_mentor_5.0.7/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/definition.rb:464:in `validate_runtime!'
    from /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@golf_mentor_5.0.7/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler.rb:101:in `setup'
    from /Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@golf_mentor_5.0.7/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /usr/local/heroku/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require
```

I am using ruby 2.5.1.  The `heroku --version` command yields `heroku-cli/6.16.13-dbb9c23 (darwin-x64) node-v9.11.1`. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this is related to this github `https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/2489`. It looks like bundler is confused by a shebang in the heroku cli file.  The solution is to use a clean environment for bundler

```
Bundler.with_clean_env {`heroku run rake db:version --remote production`}
```